# Error starting .py with roslaunch

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to start a python script to allow keyboard control of two dynamixel MX28T servo motors.

But when I try

```
roslaunch pantilt pt_keyboard.py
```

I get the following error message.

```
"Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1"
```

I thought first I could not run a .py file with roslaunch. But I saw another guy doing it. I already googled for a solution, but haven't found the answer for my specific problem.

Anybody who has an Idea?

Thanks for helping!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81016/error-starting-.py-with-roslaunch/) by [mike.sru](https://answers.ros.org/users/6656/mike.sru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roslaunch` is supposed to be used with [XML launch files](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML). However you attempting to launch a Python script.

To run Python scripts and binary executables use [rosrun](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun) instead. It also might be necessary to add 'executable' flag to that script with:

```
$ chmod a+x pt_keyboard.py
```

Otherwise `rosrun` will not run the script.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2